# Javascript Accordion - collapse other sections when one selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following vanilla Javacscript accordion working well. I am now trying to adapt my `toggle` function so that the sections other than the one selected in the accordion collapse. This is what I have so far - you will see that the sections remain open unless they are clicked to be closed:

https://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/KmeZgG

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis. Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem, animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis. Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem, animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  function toggle() {
    if (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
      var elementHeight = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight;
      this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elementHeight + 'px';
    }

    // Toggle `active` class
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  }

  var accordion = document.querySelectorAll('div.accordion .accordion-header');
  for (var i = 0, len = accordion.length; i < len; i++) {
    accordion[i].addEventListener('click', toggle);
  }

});
```

**SCSS**

```
div.accordion {
  .accordion-header {
    cursor: pointer;
    &.active {

    }
  }
  .accordion-content {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 400ms;
    &.active {
      overflow: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated - I am not using jQuery for this project.

Answer (score 1):

We can collapse all sections firstly before open the clicked one.

just add this loop at the first of toggle function:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if( x[i]==this ){ break; }
  x[i].nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
  x[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
  x[i].classList.toggle('active');
}
```

[**Updated CodePEN**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWoEyN)

```css
div.accordion .accordion-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.accordion .accordion-content {
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 400ms;
  transition: max-height 400ms;
}
div.accordion .accordion-content.active {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis. Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem, animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 1</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 2</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae at placeat nesciunt nostrum accusamus debitis fuga similique quisquam, rerum temporibus, quod asperiores nulla, eveniet libero earum eaque harum inventore minima ipsum saepe omnis. Officia, est, maiores. Reprehenderit odio perspiciatis voluptates commodi ex at praesentium laborum deleniti libero, architecto sit optio repellat est molestiae beatae, magnam qui voluptatibus. Ducimus mollitia dignissimos minus sapiente quidem, animi adipisci laboriosam aliquam asperiores facere. Repellat recusandae doloribus incidunt voluptatibus quibusdam rem delectus inventore nisi, laudantium. Doloribus eum vero, consequuntur nisi enim quam non odio dignissimos praesentium nostrum magnam consequatur totam reprehenderit quaerat. Saepe, blanditiis fugit?</p>
  </div>
  <h4 class="accordion-header">Accordion 3</h4>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  function toggle() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if( x[i]==this ){ break; }
      x[i].nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
      x[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
      x[i].classList.toggle('active');
    }
    
    if (this.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('active')) {
      
      this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute('style');
      
    } else {
      var elementHeight = this.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight;
      this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elementHeight + 'px';
    }

    // Toggle `active` class
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('active');
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  }

  var accordion = document.querySelectorAll('div.accordion .accordion-header');
  for (var i = 0, len = accordion.length; i < len; i++) {
    accordion[i].addEventListener('click', toggle);
  }

});
</script>
```